# Working on Typeahead and external JSON input is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Working on typeahead functionality for a search box and I am defining the terms manually in the js file. Instead of this I need to parse the json response to **data:[ ]** externally through an url. How can I acheive this.

```
jQuery.typeahead({
    input: '.js-typeahead-search_v1',
    order: "desc",
    source: {
        data: [
             "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
        ]
    },
    callback: {
        onInit: function (node) {
            console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which Typeahead plugin are you using? Surely their documentation shows an example of a remote data source?

Comment: start looking into using into the ajax library http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (since you're using jquery) , or if you have webpack and babel setup look into fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API to make external async calls